# Displaying my date to a specific format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am having a little difficulty with this.How can I display a date value to format `10 September 2014` using Javascript.

What I am doing at the moment is

```
var dateAdded = new Date(parseInt(user.DateAdded.substr(6)));
```

which gives me `Wed Sep 10 2014`

Comment: The [Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) provides methods for getting different parts of a date.

Comment: if you don't mind using a library I always go for http://momentjs.com/ when doing things with dates in js gives so may options for things like this including languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date)

but Marko's accepted answer there for you:

Taken from http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/javascript_date_and_time.php3:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December");

var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
document.write(curr_date + "-" + m_names[curr_month] 
+ "-" + curr_year);

//-->
</script>
```

**You can edit the array to use Jan, Feb, Mar, etc..**